# windows store app, bind to parent gridview property

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

How to bind parent property from itemTemplate gridview ?

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding UsersViewModel}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UsersTemplate}">
```

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UsersTemplate">        
        <ListView VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
                  Height="{Binding Window.Current.Bounds.Height}"   
                  Width="{Binding PARENT?.ColWidth}"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"                    
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource UserTemplateSelector}"
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LvItemStyle}" >
        </ListView>        
</DataTemplate>
```

ColWidth property is defined in UsersViewModel

Comment: Is the UsersViewModel a list of objects that have a ColWidth property?

Comment: Its a workaround, but i want to know if it's possible getting parent property directly from child item

Comment: Technically you just have to write Width={Binding ColWidth}. But there has to be a property named ColWidth in every object in the UsersViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something about your **Xaml** code doesn't feel right, since you are binding your `GridView`'s `ItemSource` to that `UsersViewModel` that feels like a `property` instead of a Collection ! (`ItemSource` should be bound to a collection).
If `UsersViewModel` is indeed a Collection of a class objects that has in it the `ColWidth` property, then a simple binding inside the `DataTemplate` should do the trick,

```
Width="{Binding ColWidth}"
```

Now if `UsersViewModel` is meant to be the `GridView`'s `DataContext`, then you code probably should look something like that,

```
<GridView DataContext="{Binding UsersViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding ACollectionInsideUsersViewModel}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UsersTemplate}">
```

In this case if the `ColWidth` property is defined inside the `UsersViewModel` object, then the easiest way to access the parent `DataContext` from a child is by using `ElementName` Binding :

```
 <GridView DataContext="{Binding UsersViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding ACollectionInsideUsersViewModel}" Name="gridView">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <ListView VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
              Height="{Binding Window.Current.Bounds.Height}"   
              Width="{Binding DataContext.ColWidth,ElementName=gridView}"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"                    
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource UserTemplateSelector}"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LvItemStyle}" >
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

Comment: Ur right, my code doesn' fill right,because i changed the variables for the example and more readability. But this not not the problem here. I know i can access the parent datacontext by using ElementName, but my datatemplate is defined in a resource file

Comment: As long that you respect you own naming the ElementName binding works well from a resource file !

Comment: Oh i didn't know that working. Thans you for ur time